# Is this the right way to get user input in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to get user input on this form, and pass it on to the other screens e.g. profile screen. I also want to show the input values when the button is pressed triggering the onPress function.

```
const SignIn = ({ navigation: { navigate } }) => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const onPress = () => {
    alert()
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Centered>
        <TextInput
          placeholder={placeholders.username}
          name="username"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          value={user.username}
          onChangeText={text => setUser(text)}
        />

        <TextInput
          placeholder={placeholders.password}
          name="password"
          autoCapitalize="none"
          password
          value={user.password}
          onChangeText={text => setUser(text)}
        />
      </Centered>

      <Centered>
        <Button onPress={onPress}>
          <Text color={colors.bright}>{buttons.send}</Text>
        </Button>
      </Centered>

    </Container>
  )
}

export default SignIn;
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, you are doing correct, when you want to pass it to other screens.. in onPress function you can pass params with props.navigation.navigate('ProfileScreen', {username : abc, password :abc}).. that is what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, that's part of what am asking for. I asked this question because in some tutorials I watched, the person used 'e => [e.target.name]: e.target.value' on the onChangeText method and it was bringing 'Undefined' errors for me.

Comment: I want to see that the values entered by the user are assigned to 'username' and 'password' when the alert pops up.

Comment: unless `text` is `{ password: value }` it's not going to be correct. your state is an object but you're passing `text` from both inputs which presumably is a string

Comment: So how do I update the values of username and password on onChangeText?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are updating your state in wrong way, you are setting the whole state object (username and password) as the value of the text input (username or password textinputs) when changing the value of any one of them. The right way would be:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({
    username: '',
    password: '',
  });
  onPress = () => {
    navigate('ProfileScreen', {username: user.username, password: user.password}) 
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        name="username"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        value={user.username}
        onChangeText={text => setUser({ username: text, password: user.password })}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        name="password"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        password
        value={user.password}
        onChangeText={text => setUser({ username: user.username, password: text })}
      />
      <Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100 }} onPress={onPress}></Button>
    </View>
)
```

Another better approach i think and you will view the most is to define two separate states one for your username and one password and updating them separately:

```
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  onPress = () => {
    navigate('ProfileScreen', {username, password})  
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        name="username"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        value={username}
        onChangeText={username => setUsername(username)}
      />
      <TextInput
        style={{ borderWidth: 1 }}
        name="password"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        password
        value={password}
        onChangeText={password => setPassword(password)}
      />
      <Button style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100, width: 100 }} onPress={onPress}></Button>
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: How can I check that the values of the states have changed (alert or console.log)? If so, how can I save them onto local storage or firebase and call these values when a user checks their profile?